# Who is Zevadyah, and why is he mentioned at the end of Hallel?

Tags: chabad, hallel

On Rosh Chodesh, after Hallel, there is the following:

> :זְבַדְיָה יִשְׁמְרֵנִי וִיחַיֵּנִי, כֵּן רָצוֹן מִלְּֿפָנֶיךָ, אֱלֹהִים חַיִּים וּמֶלֶךְ עוֹלָם אֲשֶׁר בְּיָדוֹ נֶפֶשׁ כָּל חָי, אָמֵן
>
> May *Zevadyah* protect me and grant me life. So may it be Your will, living God and eternal King, in whose hand is the soul of every living being, Amen.<sup>1</sup>

Who is Zevadyah? Why are we asking him to protect us and grant us life?
What is the source for this passage?

Interestingly enough it is not Chabad custom to recite this verse, despite its inclusion in the siddur.

---

<sup>1</sup> Siddur Tehillat Hashem, Annotated English Edition, p. 312

Comment: Zevadyah is an angel. It seems many people have a problem saying this verse because it prays to an angel. Also some have the custom not to recite the names of angels except Gabriel and Michael.

Comment: Very relevent: http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=906752&forum_id=1364

Comment: Not sure whether this helps answer the question, but many prayer books have the first word, "זבדיה", unvowelized, which I _guess_ is to signify that one should have that word in mind but not pronounce it.

Comment: Since the question is about its common inclusion in *siddurim* and its origin, I’d suggest deleting ‘Chabad’ from the title.

Comment: As per chabad minhag it's only said after hallel on Rosh chodesh and said individually before kaddish which is perhaps why you might have thought it otherwise to not be said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Zevadyah is an angel. It seems many people have a problem saying this verse because it prays to an angel. Also some have the custom not to recite the names of angels except Gabriel and Michael.
- Very relevent: bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=906752&forum_id=1364
- Many prayer books have the first word, "זבדיה", unvowelized, which I guess is to signify that one should have that word in mind but not pronounce it.

(Answers by Ezra and msh210.)

Comment: Sources? The things I said in the comments were not provided as an answer because I didn't have a valid source for my claims. I don't think you should've just copied and pasted our comments, and accepted it.

Comment: @ezra This link has the sources: bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=906752&forum_id=1364

Comment: @ezra would you rather i remove your name from the answer?

Comment: Do those people who have a problem with this also not say shalom aleichem on shabbos which is about malachim?